# Remove many UIImages with a single button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using a source code to load/rotate/zoom/move a `UIImage` from this [blog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/).

I need to remove all the images at once with a single button, I tried this:

```
[holderView removeFromSuperview];
```

But it only delete the last one created not all of them.

**EDIT**

I have another subviews in the app that i don't want them to be removed "Buttons, UIImageView, UIScrollView ..etc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use NSMutableArray to store list of UIView's

Embed this code to .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imgList;
```

Im .m file

```
@synthesize imgList;
```

After view loading

```
NSMutableArray *imgList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In the end of "imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:" add

```
[imgList addObject:holderView];
```

When you need to remove use

```
for(UIView *tempView in imgList) {
    [tempView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: No luck in that, There is a warning showing me "unused variable imgList" in viewDidLoad and it did nothing when i tried it ..

Comment: Just write **@synthesize imgList;** after @implementation. I edited my answer.

Comment: Just figure it out, I changed the `(nonatomic, assign)` to `(nonatomic, retain)` and it worked perfectly ;) thank you :)

Comment: Wrote answer in haste. Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove)
{
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Hope it helps you

EDIT :-

More efficient removal

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove)
    {
        NSArray *imagesToRemove = [v subviews];
        for (UIImageView *i in imagesToRemove)
        {
            [i removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

SECOND EDIT :-

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove)
    {
        NSArray *imagesToRemove = [v subviews];
        for (UIImageView *i in imagesToRemove)
        {
            i.image = nil;
        }
        //[v removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: ...or you can just check the kind of the `UIView` class like: `for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) [v removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: @holex have you visited tutorial mentioned above by user, in tutorial there is holderView which is UIView and inside that UIImageView is added, so both UIView which is holderView and its subview UIImageView should also be removed for memory efficiency.

Comment: to minimize code it can be written: [imagesToRemove makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]

Comment: The "More efficient removal" is grate but it removes EVERY THING including the button it self :Pp what i want is something that remove only the added images, BTW i have another UIImageView there and i want it to be set to nil not to be removed.

Comment: @Prateek, as far as I know, the `superview` keeps the `subviews` alive, rather than vice-versa. so, my suggestion is just an idea for *O(n)* and using this knowledge, your solution seems to me less more efficient a bit, but it is not a dead-or-live question, I guess.

Comment: Crash "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" .. to clarify: i want to remove the images added .. but i want to set ANOTHER imageView there to nil by `currentImg.image = nil;` i know how to do that but i told you that because i don't want to remove every thing except the added images.

Comment: @Shamlan, in that case you have to mark to added `UIImageView` objects, you can use the `tag` field for it... and you will be able to identify the added `UIImageView` objects easily. by the way, you original question is very ambiguous. :(

Comment: Sorry for that I have edited my question :) could you please explain more about the `tag` ?! I couldn't get that.